# Jquery add click event and remove it to others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to automatically close a dropdown lists when the user click on another one? The purpose is no have only one dropdown list opened at time.

Jquery:

```
jQuery(".navbar-collapse .nav li").click(function(e) {

        if(jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("span").hasClass("clicked-li")) {
            jQuery(".navbar-collapse .nav li ul").removeClass("clicked");
            jQuery(".navbar-collapse .nav li span").removeClass("clicked-li");
        }

        if ((viewport().width <= 1200)) {
            if (!jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("ul").hasClass("clicked")) {
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("ul").addClass('clicked');
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("span").addClass('clicked-li');
            } else {
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("ul").removeClass('clicked');
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("span").removeClass('clicked-li');
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
    <ul class="nav menu">
        <li class="item-101 default current active fa fa-chevron-down">
            <a href="/">Home</a><
        /li><li class="item-115 divider deeper parent fa fa-chevron-down">
        <span class="separator">XXX</span>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class="item-123 fa fa-chevron-down">
                <a href="XXX">XXX</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item-125 fa fa-chevron-down">
                <a href="XXX">XXX</a>
            </li><li class="item-126 fa fa-chevron-down">
                <a href="XXX">XXX</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It seems to be pretty bugging out for me, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It would help a lot to see your HTML too. Could you please edit your question to include it. Also note that you can remove your `if` statements and replace them with a single `toggleClass()` call

Comment: I edited it, and can does toggle class work as a if then?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for which you're not using the provided `bootstrap(.min).js` which already does what you are requesting? If you don't want to load all of `Bootstrap.js` you can customize what modules are included in it and only select the ones you want. Make sure you select `Dropdown` under `Javascript components`.

Comment: I agree with Andrei. Your class names are indicative that you've got bootstrap on the page, so just use their dropdown menu template. Easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.clicked').removeClass('.clicked');
```

But make your code a snippet, that makes it easier to help you.

But anyways do it with CSS. Its much easier.

```css
li {
  display: none;
}
a:focus li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body><ul>
<a href="#">HO

  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</a>
</ul><br>
<ul>
<a href="#">asdf
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```